# Gradle: After conversion of maven to gradle, what are the next steps to match up files?

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy

Ive been working off the guides which mention to start by doing

```
gradle init
```

on the project. So this creates build.grade. However, the rest of the gradle file is very thinly padded. Im quite new to doing these conversions, but broadly speaking, what would be the next step to get things in harmony?

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html#sec:pom_maven_conversion_) lists the following features of the Maven POM conversion:

> - Uses effective POM and effective settings (support for POM inheritance, dependency management, properties)
> - Supports both single module and multimodule projects
> - Supports custom module names (that differ from directory names)
> - Generates general metadata - id, description and version
> - Applies maven, java and war plugins (as needed)
> - Supports packaging war projects as jars if needed
> - Generates dependencies (both external and inter-module)
> - Generates download repositories (inc. local Maven repository)
> - Adjusts Java compiler settings
> - Supports packaging of sources and tests
> - Supports TestNG runner
> - Generates global exclusions from Maven enforcer plugin settings

This means, every required functionality beyond these features must be added manually, either by searching and applying plugins equivalent to the ones used in Maven or by implementing the functionality on your own.